# python: what does a method return if what it does is just raise error?

Tags: python, runtime-error, visitor-pattern

The following code snippet is from python cook book, 3rd Ed. [Chapter 8.21](https://github.com/dabeaz/python-cookbook/blob/master/src/8/implementing_the_visitor_pattern/example.py):

```
class NodeVisitor:
  
  def visit(self, node):
    methname = 'visit_' + type(node).__name__
    meth = getattr(self, methname, None)
    if meth is None:
      meth = self.generic_visit # this is the line that I have problem with
    return meth(node)

  def generic_visit(self, node):
    raise RuntimeError('No {} method'.format('visit_' + type(node).__name__))
```

As I comment in the code, I have two questions about this line:

```
meth = self.generic_visit # this is the line that I have problem with
```

1. Why self.generic_visit is parameterless?
2. more important, **generic_visit** does nothing but raising a RuntimeError, how come it returned something and assigned to "meth"?

Comment: The code simplifies to: `return getattr(self, methname, 'generic_visit')(node)`. The gist of which is: call `self.<methname>(node)` if it exists, otherwise call `self.generic_visit(node)`. Presumably, the latter method could potentially be used elsewhere in the class or reimplemented by subclasses. However, the example would be clearer if it just raised the error directly within the `vist` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`meth = self.generic_visit` makes `meth` refer to the *method* `self.generic_visit` *itself*. It does *not* refer to its return value; that would be obtained by calling `meth(x)` for some `x`.